# WordPress is replacing code with &nbsp; when I add <!DOCTYPE html> to posts

Tags: html

I have a problem while editing my post on Wordpress.
After adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` etc in the beginning of the code is keep getting replace with `& nbsp;` when I save it.
Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to enter this into the edit post page in the backend? You shouldn't need to write HTML in there, only content. The HTML doctype should be in your theme's templates.

Comment: Thanks Rub, well I am kinda new to this. I was trying to add  <!DOCTYPE html> because HTML checker is showing errors. I am basically trying to add code in "TEXT" tab in Wordpress.

Comment: The text tab of a post edit page? This isn't something you can do by changing posts and pages in the admin area, this requires code changes to the theme files, `<!DOCTYPE html>` has to be the first thing in the HTML document so it must be a theme file that gets modified. Either create a child theme, or contact your theme vendor

Comment: Thank you very much!